# python logger function does not display in endpoint

Tags: python, logging

I write an end point by Python Klein app. When I print some logging information in main function, it works well, but when I use the logger.info in end point, it does not display any logging information.

Main function:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Running as standalone python application
    cmdline_args = create_argument_parser().parse_args()

    utils.configure_colored_logging(cmdline_args.loglevel)
    pre_load = cmdline_args.pre_load

    router = DataRouter(cmdline_args.path,
                        cmdline_args.max_training_processes,
                        cmdline_args.response_log,
                        cmdline_args.emulate,
                        cmdline_args.storage)
    if pre_load:
        logger.info('Preloading....')
        if 'all' in pre_load:
            pre_load = router.project_store.keys()
        router._pre_load(pre_load)

    logger.info('Starting http server with %s threads' % cmdline_args.num_threads)

    rasa = RasaNLU(
            router,
            cmdline_args.loglevel,
            cmdline_args.write,
            cmdline_args.num_threads,
            cmdline_args.token,
            cmdline_args.cors,
            default_config_path=cmdline_args.config
    )

    logger.info('Started http server on port %s' % cmdline_args.port)
    rasa.app.run('0.0.0.0', cmdline_args.port)
```

The end point 'parse' is here:

```
class RasaNLU(object):
    """Class representing Rasa NLU http server"""
    app = Klein()
   
    def __init__(self,
                 data_router,
                 loglevel='INFO',
                 logfile=None,
                 num_threads=1,
                 token=None,
                 cors_origins=None,
                 testing=False,
                 default_config_path=None):

        self._configure_logging(loglevel, logfile)    
        self.default_model_config = self._load_default_config(
                default_config_path)   
        self.data_router = data_router
        self._testing = testing
        self.cors_origins = cors_origins if cors_origins else ["*"]
        self.access_token = token
        reactor.suggestThreadPoolSize(num_threads * 5)


    @app.route("/parse", methods=['GET', 'POST', 'OPTIONS'])
    @requires_auth
    @check_cors
    @inlineCallbacks
    def parse(self, request):
        logger.info('before_response')
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        if request.method.decode('utf-8', 'strict') == 'GET':
            request_params = decode_parameters(request)
        else:
            request_params = simplejson.loads(
                    request.content.read().decode('utf-8', 'strict'))
        ... ...
```

The line "logger.info('before_response')" does not work. Thanks for help.

Comment: Does `.parse` get called?

Comment: Yes 'parse' end point get called, but 'logger.info('before_response')' does not work.

Comment: If there is something wrong with the logging configuration, we might not be able to help unless you show us `._configure_logging`. You also might want to reduce your example to an [mre] - there is a lot of *stuff* there that we don't have access to.

Comment: Thanks. I use twisted log to solve the problem.